# JQuery verify at least one checkbox is checked with

Tags: jquery

I have an asp.net webform with a group of related checkboxes.  I would like to verify that at least one checkbox is checked in the group when a submit button is clicked. I've tried to implement two different solutions with no success. When I try to return the length of the checked checkboxes by class name, I receive 0.  When I try to return the ischecked value by name, I receive false.  If I view the source of page, the checkboxes have the "checked" attribute.  Can someone review my html and let me know if I'm doing something wrong?

```
  <tr>
      <td  colspan="2">
      <asp:CheckBox ID="cbga" runat="server"  CssClass="group1" name="group1[]" Text="A" />
      <asp:CheckBox ID="cbgb" runat="server" CssClass="group1"  name="group1[]" Text="B" />
     <asp:CheckBox ID="cbgc" runat="server" CssClass="group1"  name="group1[]" Text="C" />
</tr>

function ValChk(source, args) {
              var IsChecked = $(".group1:checked").length;//returns zero
           // var IsChecked = $('input[name="group1[]"]').is(':checked'); //returns false
              alert(IsChecked);    
        }

 <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvchks" runat="server" Display="dynamic"   
      ClientValidationFunction="ValChk" ErrorMessage="Please select a code"                                         
></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: Try the sample in here `:)` possible duplicate of [JQuery - is at least one checkbox checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941746/jquery-is-at-least-one-checkbox-checked)

Comment: Post a jsfiddle.com sample. Will get you answers easier

Comment: The pseudo class 'checked' usually works

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/GxuBp/)**</kbd>

I think that your `ValChk` doesn't trigger. See the code below. It works correctly.

### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" />

<input type="button" id="check" />
```

### jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('#check').on('click', function () {
        var IsChecked = !! $('.group1:checked').length;
        alert(IsChecked);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble determing if a checkbox is checked. Could it be related to Master pages? I tried to use the JQuery function above but I received #check).on is not a function.

Comment: Did you get `alert` or not? If you got, so there is no problem. We can handle it...

Comment: I get an alert when I used the original code I posted but it is always false or 0. When I use the code above, the alert is always false. Also, I receive the following error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: It seems that your jQuery version is old. Try using latest version of jQuery or change `on` method to `bind`: `$('#check').bind('click', function () {`.

Comment: I upated to version 1.9.1 and that seemed to have corrected the error message. However, the function is still returning false when checkboxes are checked.  If i check the length of the checked checkboxes, it is still zero.  It does not see the checked attribute for some reason.