# Validate at least one checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to validate that a check is checked, but so far have been unable to get anything to work. So far I have some Jquery that makes sure no more than one checkbox is selected.

I would appreciate any assistance to get this to work with my current code.

```
<form id="gradform" name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type='checkbox' name='may' id='may' value='1' class='unique' data-group='mog'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='august' id='august' value='2' class='unique' data-group='mog'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='december' id='december' value='3' class='unique' data-group='mog'>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.unique').click(function() {
        if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
            return;
        }
        var group = $(this).data('group');
        if (group) {
            $('input[data-group="' + group + '"]:checked').prop('checked', false);
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is my JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robp2175/TnmGr/280/)

Comment: _" makes sure no more than one checkbox is selected."_ Shouldn't you be using radio buttons for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941746/jquery-is-at-least-one-checkbox-checked

Comment: Also do not call anything "submit" in a form you might want to submit programatically

Answer (score 4):

You can use the condition that checks for the length of checked elements:

```
if($('#gradform :checkbox:checked').length){
   //checkbox is checked
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery [$.fn.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

> **Description:** Check the current matched set of elements against a
>   selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of
>   these elements matches the given arguments.

```
if($('#gradform :checkbox').is(':checked')){
   //At least on checkbox is checked
}
```